# Why did headbutting Gaara make Shukaku disintegrate?

Tags: naruto

When Naruto is fighting Gaara in the invasion of Konoha, Gaara takes on the Perfect Possession form of Shukaku. When Naruto punches Gaara in the face, it wakes him up, breaking the Possum Jutsu and making Shukaku no longer be released. When Naruto headbutts Gaara, however, Shukaku disintegrates. What causes this difference in effect?

Answer (score 3):

I think Gaara just lose control over the chakra flow when Naruto headbutted him. With that, he couldn't keep the jutsu which showed the body of Shukaku.

Comment: a strong hit on the head is enough to disorient any person. Specially when Naruto's "knuckle head" hits.. :P Its just like looper says, the hit on the head disoriented Gaara to lose control over his jutsu.

Answer (score 0):

Gaara used the "Feigning Sleep Technique" which allows the Shukaku to fully control his body and unleash its own power. However, Naruto woke Gaara up with the headbutt, which broke Shukaku's control.

Comment: No, he woke him up by punching him in the face. He then headbutts him, which causes Shukaku to shatter.